# Eigen, can;t compare matrices of the same type

Tags: c++, types, compiler-errors, eigen

I am getting the following compiler error:

```
../Src/Engine/MasterEngine/Geometry/MatrixMesh.hpp:153:31: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘SBM’ {aka ‘Eigen::SparseVector<bool, 0, int>’} and ‘SBM’ {aka ‘Eigen::SparseVector<bool, 0, int>’})
  153 |         SBM(closure_vertices) == vertices &&
```

For this code:

```
bool IsComplex(
    const Eigen::SparseMatrix<bool>& edge_matrix,
    const Eigen::SparseMatrix<bool>& face_matrix,
    const std::array<Eigen::SparseVector<bool>, 3>& simplices)
{
    SBM& vertices = simplices[0];
    SBM& edges = simplices[1];
    SBM& faces = simplices[2];

    const auto[closure_vertices, closure_edges, closure_faces] =
        Closure(edge_matrix, face_matrix, {vertices, edges, faces});

    return
        SBM(closure_vertices) == vertices &&
        SBM(closure_edges) == edges &&
        SBM(closure_faces) == faces;
}
```

I don't understand, the types are identical.

Comment: C++ doesn't generate comparison operators automatically. If Eigen doesn't provide the operators, you would need to write them yourself.

Comment: Oh dear lord, why wouldn't a lin alg library provide comparison operators...
If that's the case I am in for a ride with this lib.

Comment: I never used it, so I don't know. [Documentation I found](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseVector.html) doesn't mention it, but it could be mentioned somewhere else (since it can be a non-member function as well).

Comment: `Eigen::MatrixBase` has an [`operator==()`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a80e3e1e83fdf43f9f7fb6ff51836b24d) though, so I don't see why it isn't there for SparseVector

Comment: You can always use `a.isApprox(b)`.

Comment: `SparseMatrix<bool>` is possible, but certainly not what Eigen is aiming at. Are you sure this is the best data type for your purpose? Depending on your expected density, some sort of `set` or a `bitvector` might be a better choice.

Comment: Yes, because of how boolean arithmetic works. These matrices represent graph connectivity in a 3D mesh, which is very very sparse. Boolean arithemtic means that addition is equivalent to union, which is exactly what I need.